# How to exclude terms from search results

Tags: search, search-terms

I want users to be able to exclude words in a search, using **-** like I would in a Google search.

So for example, put **-** in front of a word you want to leave out of the search results, like *jaguar speed -car*

It does not work natively and I cannot find an extension.

Is using - (aka NOT) possible?